# How would you write to your in-class team, that you are going to drop the class, leaving no hard feelings?

Tags: email, withdraw, group-dynamics, summer-school

We have a project to do with them but I don't have the time and am not sure if this email is appropriate for them. What do you think? I would greatly appreciate your advice.

Here is what I am thinking of sending them.

*Hello guys,

Hope you having a good weekend

I’m writing to you to let you know that unfortunately and for personal reasons, I have to drop this class. I have sent an email to the professor, so he should be aware of it very soon.
I hope you understand, and I wish you guys all the best on the project.
Sincerely,*

Comment: How far into the class are you? Halfway, three weeks?

Comment: Thank you for doing this! My two colleagues in a team of 3 ghosted me in a lab project **after** the experimental work was done. I waited half a year for them to write their reports.Luckily the instructor was lenient and I had to redo only the part of the course where the reports were missing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your suggestion looks fine.  I would consider making an offer to bring them up to speed on anything you have been working on that could help them out.

Answer (score 10):

I think that your suggestion, like what Scott thought, looks perfectly fine, but you should make a few edits.

This is what I think you should send.

*Hello guys,

I hope you are having a good weekend,

I’m writing to you to let you know that unfortunately, for personal reasons, I have to drop out of this class. I have sent an email to the professor, so he will be aware of it very soon. (If you were working on something for the project, courtesy Scott) I was working on 'blah' and will send you the attachments so that you can use my work. I hope you understand, and I wish you guys the best on the project. Sincerely,*

Some points I like about your email

- You were polite
- In it you told the team why you had to leave
- And you wished them good luck/best

**Good Luck!**

Comment: Instead of "*will send you the attachments soon*", better just attach them right away :-)

Comment: K, I will edit that.

Comment: Nitpick: you missed the o in courtesy.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: What is the parenthetical supposed to mean?

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is tell them politely, whatever you say is fine, include "I'm sorry" or some similar expression of regret, what you wrote is fine.

More importantly, tell them **now**. Don't wait or spend time crafting the perfect message. The more heads up you give them the less impact you have on them. It's much more rude to wait writing the perfect email than it would be to send a poorly written email on time.

Answer (score 0):

That is just fine.  Happens all the time.  At least  you told your team.

Some of my students just disappear.